# first time launch after software update

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I need to show an alert view at first launch after the version is updated from the AppStore (1.0 to 1.1). In case the version 1.0 is not installed, the alert should not be displayed.

As far as I have understood I cannot use NSUserDefaults because it wouldn't work if the app is already installed.
The same question has been already asked but I've not understood the answer:

> You can compare the current version with the old version as follow:
>
> [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Version %@",[[NSBundle mainBundle]
>   objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"]]; 
>   And with an if statement for the current version that you know it 1.1, 2.0 ....
>   etc, you can handle it.

Can someone explain me how to do it ?
Thanks.

Comment: Why not user defaults? Store the 'current' version, then you can check on launch to see if it changed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, the alert won't be displayed on the existing app store version (1.0) if you haven't included code in that version to do it.  Uploading a new version to the app store does not alter the old version that is already installed on user devices.

You can check the version of the app as you mentioned in your question, with this code:

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"]];
```

If you go to your project settings, under the General tab there is a section called "Identity" which contains the bundle identifier, version and build strings.  Using the above code will return whatever value you set for the "Version" in your project settings.  But that may not help with what you want to do.

You want to show the alert on first launch only (and not subsequent launches) so you should use NSUserDefaults to set a flag that tells you whether or not the user has already seen the alert.  Then, at application launch you can check that value in NSUserDefaults to determine whether or not you should show the alert.

You may want to combine both of these together, however, if you expect that you will want to show another alert in future versions.  You could set a value with the "Version" string into NSUserDefaults, and call it something like "lastAlertShownForVersion" and then you will know when the user last received an alert.  Note that this value will be NULL at first when the user upgrades from 1.0 to 1.1 since it won't have been set by version 1.0 of the app.

Comment: I've implemented a check with NSUserDefaults and the alert is shown only the first time but I have not clear why I should combine the check with the current version. If I DON'T add this check and in the next version 1.2 I simply change the message of the alert (in this case a "What's new" alert), what will happen ? Last clarification: how can I display the alert only if there was a previous version already installed (i.e. if a user download version 1.1 without having 1.0 installed, it probably doesn't make sense to display the "What's new" alert) ? Thanks.

Comment: If you don't check the version number, then you are basically setting a flag in NSUserDefaults with 2 possible values: One value that tells you the alert HAS been shown, and one value that tells you the alert has NOT been shown. If you save the version number, you will have more information at your disposal.  Now you can tell whether or not the alert has been shown, AND if it was shown, what version was it shown for?

Comment: As for not showing the alert on new installs, you will need to check for some kind of saved data to determine if its a fresh install or not. This could be the NSUserDefaults data you've set, or something else your app saves.  Keep in mind that if you have already released version 1.0 without setting anything in NSUserDefaults, you may not be able to determine whether or not it is a new install at this point in time.

Answer (score 0):

there is simple start sequence:

- check if some stored in NSUserDefaults version is less than current
  started CFBundleShortVersionString version
- if need - display alert
- store current started CFBundleShortVersionString version to NSUserDefaults

if there is no NSUserDefaults with stored version - assume it's just now installed. If you don't include code for save version previously, but you save some data or files in app - you can check for it to avoid this situation.